# How can I call a function upon validation of a field using jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a multistep form where completion of one field exposes the next field.

I use a jquery remote ajax call to validate some data on the field.

Upon validation, assuming success, I want to expose the next field in the set.

**How can I use jquery validate to call a function upon SUCCESSFUL validation of a field?**

Jquery-validate includes "invalidHandler" which is called when a field validate fails, but I can't seem to find a function that is called when validation succeeds.

I've tried:

1) Using keyup to validate on keyup, but since validation is based on an ajax call, keyup is too late.

2) using the submit: function(){} parameter, but inside that I have to include another call to 'valid' to see if the field is valid, which creates recursion.

Comment: which ... uh which validation plugin are you using? can you link to it? presumably it's this one. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate ... you could hijack the "success" callback to do this, but it would require some working with.

Answer (score 0):

Does this one work for you?

```
$(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
        postValidationGoesHere();
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
   }
})
```